# How to stretch row horizontally within a container using Boostrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

The second `div` showing the table headers is not stretching as much as the one above and they are all in a `container-fluid`.
I've tried `d-flex`, `flex-grow-1`, but I believe it stretches it vertically.
[image]

I took `<div class="col">` off and the table occupies the container width wise, but then the last colun (right side) "disappears":

```
<div class="row" id="tableDiv">
    <div class="col"> 
      <div id="po-items" class="table-responsive">
        <div class="card" id="card">
          <table class="table table-hover table-vcenter" id="dtable">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th style="width:7%">Prenda</th>
                <th style="width:10%;">Cliente</th>
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" id="container2">
  <div class="row d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center align-items-stretch">
    <div class="col padding-0">
      <div id="supplierTable" class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-borderless" id="supplier">
          <thead style="white-space: nowrap">
            <tr>
              <th class="text-center">Proveedor</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="p-0">
                <select id="selectSupplier" name="select" required="required" class="custom-select" onchange="loadAddress('supplier', this);generatePoNumber('new', selectedSupplier(), '', selectedOrderPo());loadBuyersFromSS('','');loadItems('','','supplier','new','Corte')">
                  <option value=""></option>
                  <option value="artico"></option>
                  <option value="misura"></option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="address"><br></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col padding-0">
      <div id="buyerTable" class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-borderless" id="buyer">
          <thead style="white-space: nowrap">
            <tr>
              <th class="text-center">Comprador</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="p-0">
                <select id="selectBuyer" name="select" required="required" class="custom-select" onchange="loadAddress('buyer', this)">
                  <option value=""></option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="address"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col padding-0">
      <div id="billToTable" class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-borderless" id="billTo">
          <thead style="white-space: nowrap">
            <tr>
              <th class="text-center">Facturar</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="p-0">
                <select id="selectBillTo" name="select" required="required" class="custom-select" onchange="loadAddress('billTo', this)">
                  <option value=""></option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="address"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="tableDiv">
    <div class="col">
      <div id="po-items" class="table-responsive">
        <div class="card" id="card">
          <table class="table table-hover table-vcenter" id="dtable">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th style="width:7%">Prenda</th>
                <th style="width:10%;">Cliente</th>
                <th style="width:14%">Referencia</th>
                <th style="width:14%">Tela</th>
                <th style="width:10%">Color</th>
                <th style="width:4%">OS</th>
                <th style="width:4%">XS</th>
                <th style="width:4%">S</th>
                <th style="width:4%">M</th>
                <th style="width:4%">L</th>
                <th style="width:4%">XL</th>
                <th style="width:4%">2XL</th>
                <th style="width:4%">3XL</th>
                <th style="width:5%">Total</th>
                <th style="width:5%">Precio sin IVA</th>
                <th style="width:5%">Precio Total sin IVA</th>
                <th style="width:3%">Sel.</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tableRows">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried placing the second div="col" within a div="row" ?

Comment: Thanks for reading through the question and for your answer.

Comment: After I did that, now the row won't stretch vertically. I've written a question here, in case you feel like giving a hint - if that's NOT too much to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73556384/11832197