# How to vertically stretch this row div so as to take the container's width using Boostrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

If I put `class="col"`, it decreases the table width and since there is a lot of columns, each cm matters.

If I set it to `class="row"`, although I apply `class="row d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center align-items-stretch`, it doesn't stretch vertically, so I can make the most of the space in the screen.
This when this is set to `row`
[image]

Here  is the piece of `html` where this is located:

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
  </head>

<div class="col" id="tableDiv">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="po-items" class="table-responsive">
      <div class="card" id="card">
        <table class="table table-hover table-vcenter" id="dtable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th style="width:18%">Tela</th>
              <th style="width:2%; display:none">Name</th>
              <th style="width:15%">Color</th>
              <th style="width:10%">Pantone</th>
              <th style="width:15%">Contenido</th>
              <th style="width:2%; display:none">Construction</th>
              <th style="width:7%">Acho (m)</th>
              <th style="width:5%">Peso (gsm)</th>
              <th style="width:7%">Precio/m (USD)</th>
              <th style="width:8%">Metros (m)</th>
              <th style="width:10%">Precio Total sin IVA (COP)</th>
              <th style="width:5%">Sel.</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="tableRows">
            <tr>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="19677 D.Moss"></td>
              <td style="display:none">R</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="Black"></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value=""></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="79 recycled poly / 21 span"></td>
              <td style="display:none"></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="1.27"></td>
              <td><input type="number" min="0" class="item-table-values" name="numberInputs" value="235"></td>
              <td><input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" class="price" name="numberInputs" value="6.61636045" onchange="add_to_total(this)"></td>
              <td><input type="number" min="0" class="qty" name="numberInputs" value="406" onchange="add_to_total(this)"></td>
              <td class="total_price">$2,686.24</td>
              <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="19677 D.Moss"></td>
              <td style="display:none">R</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="Iron Gate"></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value=""></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="79 recycled poly / 21 span"></td>
              <td style="display:none"></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="1.27"></td>
              <td><input type="number" min="0" class="item-table-values" name="numberInputs" value="235"></td>
              <td><input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" class="price" name="numberInputs" value="6.61636045" onchange="add_to_total(this)"></td>
              <td><input type="number" min="0" class="qty" name="numberInputs" value="265" onchange="add_to_total(this)"></td>
              <td class="total_price">$1,753.34</td>
              <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="15094 D.Moss"></td>
              <td style="display:none">L</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="Wine"></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value=""></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="79 poly / 21 span"></td>
              <td style="display:none"></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="1.27"></td>
              <td><input type="number" min="0" class="item-table-values" name="numberInputs" value="235"></td>
              <td><input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" class="price" name="numberInputs" value="6.28827647" onchange="add_to_total(this)"></td>
              <td><input type="number" min="0" class="qty" name="numberInputs" value="127Add YldAdd Yld" onchange="add_to_total(this)"></td>
              <td class="total_price"><strong>$0.00</strong></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td id="totalTitle" colspan="0" align="right"><strong>Total:</strong></td>
              <td id="totalValue" class="total">$4,439.58</td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
        </table>
        <div class="row"><label for="notes">Notas:</label><textarea id="notes" name="notes" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></div><br>
        <div class="col recebido-por"><span class="recibido-por">Recibido por:</span><span class="line"></span></div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You should probably try following bootstraps grid setup completely and in the correct order else you are asking for issues to happen. Try putting everything in a container-fluid then a row and then the col with the table in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting everything in a container-fluid seems to be working and following the correct order of bootstraps grid system is important.

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
  </head>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col" id="tableDiv">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="po-items" class="table-responsive">
      <div class="card" id="card">
        <table class="table table-hover table-vcenter" id="dtable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th style="width:18%">Tela</th>
              <th style="width:2%; display:none">Name</th>
              <th style="width:15%">Color</th>
              <th style="width:10%">Pantone</th>
              <th style="width:15%">Contenido</th>
              <th style="width:2%; display:none">Construction</th>
              <th style="width:7%">Acho (m)</th>
              <th style="width:5%">Peso (gsm)</th>
              <th style="width:7%">Precio/m (USD)</th>
              <th style="width:8%">Metros (m)</th>
              <th style="width:10%">Precio Total sin IVA (COP)</th>
              <th style="width:5%">Sel.</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="tableRows">
            <tr>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="19677 D.Moss"></td>
              <td style="display:none">R</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="Black"></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value=""></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="79 recycled poly / 21 span"></td>
              <td style="display:none"></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="1.27"></td>
              <td><input type="number" min="0" class="item-table-values" name="numberInputs" value="235"></td>
              <td><input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" class="price" name="numberInputs" value="6.61636045" onchange="add_to_total(this)"></td>
              <td><input type="number" min="0" class="qty" name="numberInputs" value="406" onchange="add_to_total(this)"></td>
              <td class="total_price">$2,686.24</td>
              <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="19677 D.Moss"></td>
              <td style="display:none">R</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="Iron Gate"></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value=""></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="79 recycled poly / 21 span"></td>
              <td style="display:none"></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="1.27"></td>
              <td><input type="number" min="0" class="item-table-values" name="numberInputs" value="235"></td>
              <td><input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" class="price" name="numberInputs" value="6.61636045" onchange="add_to_total(this)"></td>
              <td><input type="number" min="0" class="qty" name="numberInputs" value="265" onchange="add_to_total(this)"></td>
              <td class="total_price">$1,753.34</td>
              <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="15094 D.Moss"></td>
              <td style="display:none">L</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="Wine"></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value=""></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="79 poly / 21 span"></td>
              <td style="display:none"></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="1.27"></td>
              <td><input type="number" min="0" class="item-table-values" name="numberInputs" value="235"></td>
              <td><input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" class="price" name="numberInputs" value="6.28827647" onchange="add_to_total(this)"></td>
              <td><input type="number" min="0" class="qty" name="numberInputs" value="127Add YldAdd Yld" onchange="add_to_total(this)"></td>
              <td class="total_price"><strong>$0.00</strong></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td id="totalTitle" colspan="0" align="right"><strong>Total:</strong></td>
              <td id="totalValue" class="total">$4,439.58</td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
        </table>
        <div class="row"><label for="notes">Notas:</label><textarea id="notes" name="notes" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></div><br>
        <div class="col recebido-por"><span class="recibido-por">Recibido por:</span><span class="line"></span></div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go...

Add the following CSS:

```
#dtable {
  width: 100vw !important;
}
```

Let me know if this solves your problem.

See the snippet below.

```css
#dtable {
  width: 100vw !important;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<div class="col" id="tableDiv">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="po-items" class="table-responsive">
      <div class="card" id="card">
        <table class="table table-hover table-vcenter" id="dtable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th style="width:18%">Tela</th>
              <th style="width:2%; display:none">Name</th>
              <th style="width:15%">Color</th>
              <th style="width:10%">Pantone</th>
              <th style="width:15%">Contenido</th>
              <th style="width:2%; display:none">Construction</th>
              <th style="width:7%">Acho (m)</th>
              <th style="width:5%">Peso (gsm)</th>
              <th style="width:7%">Precio/m (USD)</th>
              <th style="width:8%">Metros (m)</th>
              <th style="width:10%">Precio Total sin IVA (COP)</th>
              <th style="width:5%">Sel.</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="tableRows">
            <tr>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="19677 D.Moss"></td>
              <td style="display:none">R</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="Black"></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value=""></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="79 recycled poly / 21 span"></td>
              <td style="display:none"></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="1.27"></td>
              <td><input type="number" min="0" class="item-table-values" name="numberInputs" value="235"></td>
              <td><input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" class="price" name="numberInputs" value="6.61636045" onchange="add_to_total(this)"></td>
              <td><input type="number" min="0" class="qty" name="numberInputs" value="406" onchange="add_to_total(this)"></td>
              <td class="total_price">$2,686.24</td>
              <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="19677 D.Moss"></td>
              <td style="display:none">R</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="Iron Gate"></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value=""></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="79 recycled poly / 21 span"></td>
              <td style="display:none"></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="1.27"></td>
              <td><input type="number" min="0" class="item-table-values" name="numberInputs" value="235"></td>
              <td><input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" class="price" name="numberInputs" value="6.61636045" onchange="add_to_total(this)"></td>
              <td><input type="number" min="0" class="qty" name="numberInputs" value="265" onchange="add_to_total(this)"></td>
              <td class="total_price">$1,753.34</td>
              <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="15094 D.Moss"></td>
              <td style="display:none">L</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="Wine"></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value=""></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="79 poly / 21 span"></td>
              <td style="display:none"></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tableInputs" value="1.27"></td>
              <td><input type="number" min="0" class="item-table-values" name="numberInputs" value="235"></td>
              <td><input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" class="price" name="numberInputs" value="6.28827647" onchange="add_to_total(this)"></td>
              <td><input type="number" min="0" class="qty" name="numberInputs" value="127Add YldAdd Yld" onchange="add_to_total(this)"></td>
              <td class="total_price"><strong>$0.00</strong></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td id="totalTitle" colspan="0" align="right"><strong>Total:</strong></td>
              <td id="totalValue" class="total">$4,439.58</td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
        </table>
        <div class="row"><label for="notes">Notas:</label><textarea id="notes" name="notes" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></div><br>
        <div class="col recebido-por"><span class="recibido-por">Recibido por:</span><span class="line"></span></div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```